# Flex Box not working in Safari

Tags: css

I am working on understanding the flex box and seem to be having issues with it working while testing the code on CodePen in Safari. Please take a look and help me to understand what it is about the flex box that I am not doing correctly.

http://codepen.io/pertrai1/full/FKcGJ

Thank you

**Update:** My use case is that I am working on a tutorial that is showing me how to make use of the flex box. What I am expecting is that when I use the flex box for the selectors that each of the div's should align next to each other in the parent div without having to use floats. Right now I don't see this happening.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What do you expect and what is the outcome?

Comment: From what I see, the boxes are not sitting next to each other like they should from what I understand is to happen when using the flex box. Do you see anything different when you look at it. Are they next to each other? That is what I am looking for them to do and I don't see them doing that and don't know why.

Comment: Pertrai, you should update your question to include a description of what you expect and why the results don't match up with your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [working version on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/full/kcLGu). I think you were just following an old tutorial. [There's a good one here at this link.](http://umaar.github.com/css-flexbox-demo/) Also remember that child elements inherit their attributes from their parents by default. There seemed to be a lot of unnecessary code. Maybe you can explain what else you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Alex, thank you for sharing this with me. I was able to update my use case and get a better understanding of the use of flex box. I was working through the book, The Book of CSS3, which must be using out dated code. I will pay attention to this and check with the w3c to make sure my code is up to date with how the modules are currently recommended. Thank you again.